# Windows appears to be booting from recovery partition, but everything is fine?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

This is not a problem, but rather a mystery.

I am dual-booting windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.4.  Grub is clearly pointing to a windows boot loader on my recovery partition.  It says something like "Windows (loader) on dev/sta2, which I am certain is my recovery partition.

Nonetheless, Windows boots absolutely normally, as far as I can tell.  Everything about my windows system is exactly as it was before I installed Ubuntu.

Does this strike anyone else as odd?  My expectation would be for the windows boot loader to be on the same partition as the operating system.  In case it should happen to be relevant, I once tried to re-install windows from the recovery partition, and it didn't work.  (I forget why not... some files missing maybe.)

Just curious if anyone has any insight for a curious person such as myself.  Is this truly weird, or is there a puzzle piece I simply don't have?

Many thanks!

Comment: did you install windows before or after you insalled ubuntu

Comment: Windows loader it's not your recovery partition, its windows.

Comment: @Rarda, I installed windows first.)

Comment: @lapisdecor (and everyone really), I see that there's something I don't understand, and I'm trying to fill in the gap and figure out how it all works.  My hypothesis is that the windows loader is on the recovery partition (for some reason,) but that it's pointing to something on the C drive.  Could that be the case?